# How to poke a Vector (or to get a Ptr Vector to it's data)?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I've read that [Data.Vector.Storable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html) stores it's elements in a consecutive memory region. I've been expecting that `Vector` would be an instance of `Foreign.Storable` or at least there would be a function `:: Vector a -> Ptr (Vector a)`, but there is only `unsafeToForeignPtr0 :: Storable a => Vector a -> (ForeignPtr a, Int)`.

My Haskell code produces a list of `Foreign.Storable` things and i want access this list from the C code. Is `Vector.Storable` right data type to do this, and if yes - how should i access it's elements from the C side?

Comment: Does [`Foreign.ForeignPtr.Safe.withForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr-Safe.html#v:withForeignPtr) (or even [`Foreign.ForeignPtr.Unsafe.unsafeForeignPtrToPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr-Unsafe.html)) help?

Comment: @Tinctorius, well, there is even http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable-Internal.html module, but that `unsafe`ness scares me. If i "cast" `ForeignPtr` to `Ptr`, would it prevent Haskell's garbage collector from deleting it?

Comment: I changed my comment; you can use `withForeignPtr` from `Foreign.ForeignPtr.Safe`, too, if you can turn the code that uses it into an IO-monadic action.

Comment: Hmm... i was planning to call Haskell from C, not C from Haskell. Is there another way besides `withForeignPtr`?

Comment: I have very little experience with the FFI. Could you make a "trampoline" function in Haskell, one that is easy to invoke from the C code, that handles the `withForeignPtr`?

Comment: @Tinctorius, whoa, that's an idea! Will try.

Comment: use `pokeArray`, not `poke`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not changing the memory from C, you can use [`unsafeWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html#g:36). If you do need to make changes from C, you can copy the vector first, or make a copy on the C side. (In case you do need to make changes from C, but don't need the data on the Haskell side any more, you can also use `unsafeWith` without copying, but then you have to make sure that the vector is never again used. This can be tricky, with laziness and all...)

So, why isn't `Vector a` an instance of `Storable` when `a` is? Well, for one: what should [`sizeOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Storable.html#v%3asizeOf) be for a vector? Recall that even though that function has signature `(Storable a) => a -> Int`, the documentation says "the argument is not used". Hopefully someone who knows the internals comes around and gives an authoritative answer, but as far as I know, all the `Storable` instances are "fixed-size" types.

Addendum: The function signatures you're requesting can't really make sense. Suppose you had a `foo :: Vector a -> Ptr (Vector a)`, would it really make sense that `foo (fromList [1,2]) == foo (init (fromList [1,2,3]))`? Remember, these are now *pointers*, and could very well be different.

Comment: It is possible to implement `Storable a => Storable (Vector a)` if `Vector a` is stored as a `struct {int length; void *array;};` type in C.  Still, I'd favor using `unsafeWith`.

Comment: @Heatsink: I'm probably just confused, but how do you define `sizeOf` in that case? (I do realize that `(Storable a) => Vector a` nicely corresponds to a struct like the one you sketch, and that it's easy to write the correct `poke` and `peek` for it -- but it still isn't really an instance of `Storable`, is it?)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
import qualified Foreign.Ptr as P
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as SV
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable.Internal as SVI
import qualified GHC.ForeignPtr as FP

ptr0ToVector :: SV.Storable a => P.Ptr a -> Int -> IO (SV.Vector a)
ptr0ToVector ptr size =
 FP.newForeignPtr_ ptr >>= \foreignPtr ->
 return (SV.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 foreignPtr size)

vectorToPtr0 :: SV.Storable a => SV.Vector a -> (P.Ptr a,Int)
vectorToPtr0 vector =
 let (foreignPtr,size) = SV.unsafeToForeignPtr0 vector
 in (SVI.getPtr foreignPtr,size)
```

Comment: These functions actually work! I tested them with screen captures and they work like charm. :)